Sorting structs with constant members
I have a POD struct S with const members and a std::vector<S> vec that I'd like to sort. The following won't compile:
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const S& s1, const S& s2){return s1.x < s2.x;};

because operator= isn't well-defined on S, and so this fails to compile. Is there any STL friendly way to sort vec that plays well with <algorithm>? I'll add that my const members are conceptually const (each S object should be immutable), but they absolutely can change.
Additionally, we never use the original vector after it gets sorted.
Here is the best solution I could come up with:
https://godbolt.org/z/8sxzoee1o
We create a vector of indices into vec and sort that vector using our comparator, and then reconstruct what the sorted vec would look like.

Keep in mind that std::sort is an in-place sorting algorithm, so the element type absolutely must be assignable in order for the algorithm to work. What you implemented is an out-of-place sorting method. It is possible to implement an in-place sorting algorithm but you would need to use something instead of assignment like std::destroy_at and std::construct_at to actually end the lifetime of an object and start a new lifetime every time you want to assign a new value. At that point though I would consider rethinking these conflicting requirements and relaxing one of them.

std::sort() requires the elements to satisfy the requirements of Swappable, MoveConstructible, and MoveAssignable. S is neither Swappable nor MoveAssignable, hence the error.  So you simply can't sort a vector<S> directly, only indirectly as you already discovered.

It’s very rare to have a sufficient reason to have a const non-static data member.  If you don’t want to change S objects, use const S& in appropriate places, possibly via encapsulation at a higher level (e.g., containing the whole std::vector<S>).

Here is the best solution I could come up with -- Already explained here in the third item.

Following the comments above, can you explain why do you actually need the members in S to be const ?

@wohlstad The object that I'm representing is conceptually immutable (I never want it to change and I never want to give an option for future programmers working with my code to change it). Perhaps I should just make the members mutable and pass around const S's instead though

It's up to you. Using const S istead of making the members themselves const will make things a lot easier (and also seems more appropriate anyway IMHO).
